# What are wakelocks in android and how do we apply them?

Tags: android, sdk

What are wakelocks in android ? Is it like switching the power state of a phone? What class in Android API do we require inorder to apply them?

Comment: I think you mean Wakelocks (not wavelocks).

Comment: Yes.. sorry for the typo

Answer (score 0):

API level 1

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PowerManager;

public class DoNotDimScreen extends Activity  {

private PowerManager.WakeLock wl;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle.      savedInstanceState) {
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "DoNotDimScreen");
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    wl.release();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    wl.acquire();
   }
}
```

You will need to include this permission in your manifest:

android.permission.WAKE_LOCK

Answer (score 0):

Wake Lock is used in some cases where we need to keep the device on for more than normal time, like while creating some night clock apps where the screen has to remain on.

You have to use

```
 import android.os.PowerManager.WakeLock;
```